# How can I specify JVM flags in a Go SBT task?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, jvm-arguments, go-cd

I am building a Java+Scala multi-module project with SBT using Go CD and the [gocd-sbt-plugin](https://github.com/jmnarloch/gocd-sbt-plugin). However, I am running out of memory (`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`) when I attempt to compile and package the modules.

In Jenkins CI, the SBT plugin gives me options to add JVM flags and sbt flags in the build action. Currently we are using these JVM flags:

`-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xss2M`

I have not found answers in Go documentation or by trying to put the above arguments in the 'Additional options' textbox.

[image: Edit SBT task screenshot]

When I tried the latter, I got this stacktrace:

```
15:02:23.288 [info] Compiling 54 Scala sources and 3495 Java sources to /gocd/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/de/component/build/scala-2.11/classes...
15:04:31.744 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
15:04:31.744    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
15:04:31.744    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
... 
15:04:31.744    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
15:04:31.744 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
15:04:31.744    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:394)
15:04:31.744    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
...
15:04:31.744    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5373)
15:04:31.744 [error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
15:04:31.744 [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
15:04:31.760 [error] Expected key
15:04:31.760 [error] Expected '*'
15:04:31.760 [error] XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
15:04:31.760 [error]    ^
15:04:31.858 Error: Interaction with plugin with id 'sbt.task.plugin' implementing 'task' extension failed while requesting for 'execute'. Reason: [Unsuccessful response from plugin. Plugin returned with code '500' and the following response: '{"exception":null,"success":false,"message":"Build failure"}']
15:04:31.865 [go] Current job status: failed.
```

I believe the task is still failing because it is not using these flags which result in a successful Jenkins build. Can someone point out where I can pass the above JVM flags into my Go SBT task?

Comment: I don't know what you ended up doing, but for me the flag `-mem 4096` (e.g. 4 GB) did the trick for a similar project, which might also work in this case. E.g. `sbt package -mem 4096`

Answer (score -1):

Try passing

```
-J-Xmx2G
-J-Xss2M
```

etc. as additional options (see https://medium.com/@jan______/sbtconfig-is-deprecated-650d6ff10236).